# How to get all date data from specific month from xml file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I have a code that allows me to fetch xml data from a url and I am trying to figure out how to display all the date data for each specific month. I manage to split the date (dd/mm/yyyy format) by splitting with("/") method. How do i get all the date data from each specific month?

```
console.log("Fetching from URL: ", currenturl);

            fetch(currenturl)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
              const parser = new DOMParser();
              const xml = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
              
              var getdate = xml.getElementsByTagName("date");
              
              var amountOfdate = getdate.length;


              //display the total amount of date element in the xml file.
              console.log(amountOfdate);
              
                    
              for (let i = 0; i < amountOfdate; ++i){

                
                var getstringdate =  getdate[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                var arrmonth = getstringdate.split("/");

                var getmonth =  parseInt(arrmonth[1]);

                
                  

                 }
                

                
              }
              console.log("stop");
            })
            .catch(console.error);
```

Xml example(i have a big amount of data)

```
<datedata>
    <month>
        <date>01/01/2007</date> 
    </month>

    <month>
        <date>01/01/2007</date> 
    </month>

    <month>
        <date>01/02/2007</date> 
    </month>
</datedata>
```

How to get all the data that has the getmonth value of 1?

```
result in console.log : 
01/01/2007
01/01/2007
```

Comment: Can u give a sample set of the input Data? ... and what you would like to have as your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = `
<datedata>
  <month>
      <date>01/01/2007</date> 
  </month>

  <month>
      <date>01/01/2007</date> 
  </month>

  <month>
      <date>01/02/2007</date> 
  </month>
</datedata>`;

  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xml = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
  const dates = xml.getElementsByTagName("date");

  const result = Array.from(dates)
      .map(date => date.childNodes[0].nodeValue)
      .filter(dateString => {
          const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('/');
          return month === '01'
      })
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the dates stay the same in this format you can check if the date contains the month as string

```js
const month = '01'
let dates = getDate.filter(date => {
  return date.includes(`/${month}/`)
})
```